# Is MSDTC a big resource drain?

Tags: c#, msdtc, csla

**So, Is MSDTC a big resource drain on a system (server & application)?**

In the past, I have written several large scale web applications that rely on MSDTC for database transactions.  I have never investigated how much of a drain that would be on the server.

Currently, I am working with CSLA framework and CSLA doesn't rely on MSDTC for transactions.  It basically reuses the same connection object and executes all database commands within a *TransactionScope* object.

I guess I am looking for some arguments either way as to using MSDTC or not.

Comment: I guess it is.  My other 2 choices is doing what CSLA does or write out a stored procedure with the sql.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSTDC is used for **distributed** transaction. To simplify, using a `TransactionScope` can implicitely use MSDTC if the transaction needs to be distributed, ie: if the TransactionScope surrounds a piece of code that implies more than one resource. This is called escalation, and most of the time happens automatically.

So, yes it takes somes resources, but if you do need [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) transaction across multiple systems ("resource managers", like SQL Server, Oracle, or MSMQ for example) on a Windows OS, you don't have much choice but use MSDTC.

One thing about performance that can be done when configuration MSDTC, is ensure there is only one Coordinator for a pool of distributed resources, avoiding MSDTC to MSDTC communication. Configuration is usually the biggest problem you'll face with MSDTC. Example here: http://yrushka.com/index.php/security/configure-msdtc-for-distributed-transactions/

Answer (score 2):

Compared to you application probably not. I use it on my current project and I have never noticed it affecting the CPU resources. What you do have to be careful about is latency, if there are multiple servers involved in your transaction that will be a much bigger problem than CPU.

Another way to look at is, its not going to be CPU bound, execution will be based on IO. Of course this assumes you don't do a lot of computation in your transaction, but that's not DTC's fault now is it?

Answer (score 1):

I have used MSDTC for transactions enrolling multiple partners (one or more DB servers and one or more servers using MSMQ). The drain of using MSDTC in terms of performance vs. using transactions in general isn't a big deal. We were processing more than 40 million messages a data through MSMQ and every single one had a db action as well (though some were just cached reads, not many though).

The biggest problem is MSDTC is a huge pain in the but when you are crossing zones (e.g. DMZ to intranet). Getting stuff to enroll when they are in different zones is possible but takes tweaking. DTC also has a large number of configuration options if you are interested.